# If my class manages a resource correctly then what is the point in having smart poointers?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

I am new to smart pointers, I liked using them for the safety and power of sharing object...

I have one question: If my class manages a resource in its constructors and destructors applying some rules of thumb like the Big 5 and the Big 3... Should I still use smart pointers? or my class is an alternative to them. Because as I've read in C++ primer 5 edition that smart pointers came to solve problems raw pointers were facing like memory-leaks, double-deleting pointers and accessing a dangling pointer... My class can avoid those problems:

```
class BallGame {
    public:
        using Resource = int;

        BallGame(int);
        BallGame(const BallGame&);
        BallGame(BallGame&&);
        BallGame& operator=(const BallGame&);
        BallGame& operator=(BallGame&&);
        ~BallGame();
    private:
        Resource m_res;
};
```

- Consider that the member of my class are doing the right job so can I avoid smart pointer?
- I want to know some scenarios when I should use smart pointers rather than managing resources in my class.
- Are they really for "dumb classes" (classes that define constructors but not well-behaved destructors) like in C++ primer book.

Comment: Most resources can be handled by smart pointer and custom deleter, avoiding to write custom class to handle them (or is a way to implement it).

Comment: Why using Rule of 3/5 when you can have rule of 0 :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question can be read as

> If I implement correct semantics for memory ownership of a smart pointer by hand in each class I use, can I avoid using smart pointers?

**Yes**, but why? When you need a dynamic array do you reimplement basic `std::vector` semantics by hand every time you need it? I don't think so.

It's the purpose of libraries, avoiding reinventing the wheel every time.

Comment: Thank you! But my class can have an `std::vector` as a data member.

Comment: And you can have a `std::unique_ptr<Foo>` as a data member, I don't see the difference.

Comment: Also note: It can be surprisingly difficult to manage the resources by hand. It's not just "make sure it's set correctly in plain constructor and cleared in destructor", you also typically want the various assignment operators to provide even a basic exception guarantee (no memory leaks if exception occurs), let alone strong exception guarantees, need to make sure move construction/assignment leaves the instance being emptied in a legal state for the destructor, etc. Proper use of smart pointers and other managed resources usually means you don't have to even *write* all of that.

Comment: Yep. Your number one problem isn't the bugs you expected. If you've got any hope of survival, you've eliminated all of the known risks that can be eliminated and mitigated the rest. It's the stuff you didn't see coming that gets you.

Answer (score 1):

Another benefit of smart pointers that has not been mentioned yet is that they give whoever is reading the code a decent idea of the lifetime of that object. The thing with a raw pointer is (especially as code gets more complicated) it can be difficult to figure out who is responsible for calling delete on the object whereas if you have a unique pointer instead we know immediately that the deletion will happen automatically when the pointer goes out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

As you've read in your book: They solve the issues raw-pointers facing thus: consider this:

```
int* ptr = new int[1024];
// oh my God! forgot to free it then welcome to memory leak

std::string* pStr = new std::string("Hello");
delete pStr;

//...
// and at some point in the program you think it is time to free pStr which has been already freed (among hundreds of code lines) then welcome to U.B.
 std::cout << *pStr << std::endl; // pStr is a dangling pointer. U.B
```

To solve this using smart pointers:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> upi = std::make_unique(7);
// use upi effectively and don't care about freeing it because it automatically will be freed for you.
```

- Another reason your class cannot support is sharing the same object among many objects effectively. In fact you can achieve that through applying a shallow-copy in your class but the Problem is who will free that resource then you end up implementing the functionality of a shared_ptr in your maybe small class!
- Each new version of C++ comes with new facilities and new powerful features so you should stick to these libraries instead re-inventing the well. If only for some educational reason then it is OK to practice.
- If you look you'll find real programs contains smart pointers as members which make your class robust.